# How to use timestamp with two IF in multiple sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to put a timestamp in two columns in Google spreadsheet: if the value in column C has been changed, put a timestamp in column O, and if the value in column D has been changed, put a timestamp in column P. It has to apply for multiple sheets.

I have written a code but currently, no matter if I change the value in column C or D, it puts the same timestamp in both columns O and P. What do I need to change? Thank you!

This is my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col === 3 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 1" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 2" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 3" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 4" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 5" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 6" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 7" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 8" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 9" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 10"  ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,15).setValue(new Date())
  }

  if(col === 4 && row > 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 1" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 2" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 3" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 4" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 5" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 6" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 7" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 8" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 9" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 10"  ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,16).setValue(new Date())
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace these many lines `"Играч 1"` with one:

`if ( e.source.getActiveSheet().getName().search(/Играч [0-9]+/) < 0 ) return;`

```
function onEdit(e) {

    if ( e.source.getActiveSheet().getName().search(/Играч [0-9]+/) < 0 ) return;

    var row = e.range.getRow();
    if (row <= 3) return;

    var col = e.range.getColumn();
    if(col === 3) e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,15).setValue(new Date());
    if(col === 4) e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,16).setValue(new Date());

}
```

The regexp `/Играч [0-9]+/` means `'Играч ' + any number`.

If you need the range `1..10` rather than any number I'd propose this condition:

```
...
var sheet_name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName().split(' ');
if (sheet_name[0] != 'Играч') return;
if (sheet_name[1] < '1') return;
if (sheet_name[1] > '10') return;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col === 3 && row > 3 && (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 1" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 2" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 3" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 4" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 5" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 6" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 7" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 8" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 9" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 10")  ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,15).setValue(new Date())
  }

  if(col === 4 && row > 3 && (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 1" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 2" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 3" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 4" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 5" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 6" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 7" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 8" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 9" 
    || e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Играч 10")  ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,16).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to limit this action of one sheet I would guess otherwise it will happen on all of your sheets.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart > 2 && e.range.columnStart < 5) {
    e.range.offset(0,13).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```